# Display second min variation price of a variable Product in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm using the following script:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

$price = '';

if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) {
    $price .= '<span style="display:none;" class="not-from">v.a. ' . _x('', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
    
    $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
}

return $price;
}
```

It does show the *min* variation price at this moment. I want to create the following:

- If the min price is 0,00, then show the 2nd  product variation price.

E.g.: Product X has 3 different variations: 1 (€0,00), 2 (€5,00), 3 (€15,00). If the variation price is 0,00, then show the second price variation, €5,00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to display the 2nd min variable price whenthe min price is equal to **`0`**:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price_html', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    // Get all variations prices
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    // Get the prices (min and max)
    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
    $max_price = end( $prices['price'] );

    // Get 2nd min price
    $min_price2_arr = array_slice($prices['price'], 1, 1);
    $min_price2 = $min_price2_arr[0];

    if ( $min_price > 0) {
        $price = wc_price( $min_price );
    } elseif ( $min_price == 0 ) {
        $price = wc_price( $min_price2 );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This is code tested and works only in WooCommerce 3+.

Comment: I think `$min_price2` can also be taken with `$min_price2 = next( $prices['price'] );`

Comment: @Reigel, Unfortunally the _next_ rule does not work. Any other idea?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: The adjustment did not worked for me. Looks like var #min_price2 is not set.